# Gradual Migration from Angular 1.x to Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

We have an application that is build using Angular 1.6. We plan to migrate it to Angular Universal to make use of server-side rendering. However we plan to do it gradually (per page) due to time constraints.

Any suggestions on how to plan the roadmap out would be great. Is there a way to serve some pages in Angular Universal and some pages in Angular 1.x?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different potential configurations for Angular Universal. For this QuickStart, we are going to focus on the most common setup which includes:

Angular 2 (obviously!)
Node.js back end
Webpack